# Encryption/decryption across multiple platforms (iOS, Android, WP7 and PHP)

Tags: php, security, cross-platform, encryption

I'm building an application across multiple mobile devices (iOS, Android and WP7). These platforms send data to the same server, which runs PHP (Apache 2).

What I would like to achieve is to encrypt all data that needs to be sent to the server, using the same algorithm and private key on each mobile device.
PHP should then decrypt this data with the same private key.

Is there any common solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to secure the connection from the apps to the server or do you want to secure your data from the end users on the phones? The former can be achieved by using SSL.

Comment: +1, SSL is used exactly for secure transfer between peers over open networks.

Comment: Even I had a similar question. How do I secure my data using any encryption algorithm that should be available from all platforms(Symbian - C++, Android - Java, Server - PHP)?

Comment: @emaillenin I cannot talk about Symbian, but Android, iOS, WP7 and Apache (I guess you run PHP on an Apache) all handle SSL-encrypted connections with little configuration and programming effort. I have spent more time in getting deserialization of JSON data working in Android and WP7 than in securing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

http://scrypt.codeplex.com

This allows you to use RSA for encryption from your WP7 device.  You would only need to keep the public key on your devices to do the encryption and use the private key from your web site/service (PHP) to decrypt the data.  This way you won't be exposing your key in your application as you would with a symmetric scheme like AES.

Answer (score 0):

Try AES ECB encryption and decryption, you will find libraries for all the platforms.

For PHP take a look here http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net

With this library you can encrypt and decrypt data and than you can also look for Base16 encoding/decoding.

Comment: ECB is insecure ryt?